# How to integrate ZRP routing protocol in OMNET++ for FANET?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, simulator, ns2, inet

Integration of ZRP routing protocol in OMNET++

I am trying to do a project on FANET using OMNET simulator.

OMNET version: 6.0.1
INET: 4.4
OS: Windows

Can someone please guide me how to integrate ZRP in OMNET++. I found out that INET framework doesn't support ZRP. Is there a way to do it though? If you could guide me or give me link to something (code) that could be helpful? Thank you so much.

Also, can someone tell me what tools do i need to simulate FANET in OMNET.

Thanks again,
Amy

Comment: ns2 : Geo3D+zrp_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WMJLgjq1BqaFWFKsJ0DKWJ7aYfIjdMZN/view?usp=sharing .... **3D ex** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0FIaCMV6d5PSEeDUPgmiFlFC8KMbZvh/view?usp=sharing .... **zrp ex** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VOOdQoLjpFijLKXkYGjrMYDJSFKWvnmT/view?usp=sharing